OpenCascade - Segment to segment intersection
I have searched a lot in the web but I was not able to find an out-of-the-box function for computing segment-to-segment intersection with OCCT.
It seems to me quite a common problem, but apparently OCCT only provides curve-to-surface intersector (GeomAPI_IntCS) and surface-to-surface intersector (GeomAPI_IntSS); for sure I can implement custom logic for handling the various result cases (no intersections, point interesection, segment intersection) but I thought such a library should provide what I need.
So the question is: did I missed it or actually it's not provided?

In 2D, there are only two cases: If lines are not co-linear (parallel) they do intersect in a finite point. In 3D, there is third (and very common) case: skew lines, i.e. they neither intersect nor are co-linear. (This may even result from round-off errors.) So, the common case in 3d is to determine the shortest distance between two lines. A short look into google uncovered gp_Lin::Distance(). (Admittedly, I don't know much about OCCT.)

gp_Lin::Distance() Computes the distance between two lines.; as you highlighted in 3D the segment-to-segment intersection is more complex (e.g.: co-linear segments can not intersect even if the underlying lines have 0 distance, segments not intersecting can have intersecting underlying lines, etc...). I am surprised OCCT does not provide it explictly, so I am asking if I missed it.
